# Page reloading when hitting enter on a form

Tags: javascript

Yes this question has been asked for, no the answers don't seem to be working for me.

Simply put, here's the code:

```
   <form id="frm1" onsubmit="preventDefault();">
  Message: <input type="text" name="message"><br>

  <input type="button" onclick="sendMessage()">
    </form>

<script>
function sendMessage() {
    var message = document.getElementById("frm1").message.value;
    socket.emit('browsermsg', {data: message})
}
$("frm1").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    sendMessage();
    alert("call some function here");
 });
</script>
```

using `onsubmit="preventDefault();"` doesn't have any effect, where as using `"onsubmit="return false;"` prevents the from from being submitted at all when enter is pressed.

I want the form to submit when enter is pressed, but then to also not reload the page. I'm failing to see where in code the page feels the need to reload when the enter key is pressed at all, I'm assuming it's something built into JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$("frm1").submit(function (e) {` should be `$("#frm1").submit(function (e) {`

As you are selecting from by Id, this is how you use the selector with id `$('#Id')`

Comment: That was it, thank you very much. Cant' set the answer for another 8 minutes tho :p

Comment: Glad to know if this was helpful.  One minute to go :p